# Get base64 from local file path (Windows) with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, filepath

I need to get **base64** of an image file.

All I am given is the local file path of the file like this : `C:\APPL\scans\IMG555.jpg`

I tried this piece of code but doesn't seem to work.

```js
var name = 'IMG555.jpg';
var path = '`C:\APPL\scans\';

export const fileToBase64 = (filename, filepath) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var file = new File([filename], filepath);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Read file content on file loaded event
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    // Convert data to base64 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};

fileToBase64(name , path).then(result = {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I only get a part (small length) of base64. So, it's not a valid image file.

Anybody got a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Are you in an environment like nwjs or electron, or can the user select that file via drag/drop or a `<input type="file" />`? Otherwise, you'll not be able to read any file from the user's disk for security reasons.

Comment: Also, there's a backtick at the start of your `path` string which probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: The code of yours seems invalid!

Answer (score 0):

In browser environments, you can't just read any file from the disk for security reasons. The user must explicitly select a file, for example using `<input type="file" />`.

This is a simple example which displays the base64 representation of the selected file in a `textarea`. You don't need jQuery to do this.

```js
function showBase64Representation() {
  var output = document.querySelector('textarea');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    output.value = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="showBase64Representation()"><br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```